# how to add water mark to a photo during uploading in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Place watermark image on other images (C#, ASP.Net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224653/place-watermark-image-on-other-images-c-asp-net)

how to add water mark to a photo during uploading in asp.net ???

Comment: You're in luck! It looks like someone else has already written most of the code for you: [Place watermark image on other images (C#, ASP.Net)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224653/place-watermark-image-on-other-images-c-asp-net) (And good thing, because nobody was going to do it here. In the future, please try and put some more effort into your questions. I guarantee it will solicit better answers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run ImageMagick ( http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) from your asp.net script after the upload process, and put the required watermark.
a general example here :

http://foobarist.com/how-to-watermark-images-using-imagemagick-composite-on-the-command-line