# Convert image from one format to another

Tags: c#, winforms, imagemagick

I need to convert image from one format, some big format, to some lite format like jpg or any other.

I am using winforms, C#. What class is best for this job, and any suggestion what is a good way to do this?

I find Imagemagic. I guess it's the right way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What format are you converting from? If it's bitmaps and you don't need fine-grained control over the image, just use the built in conversions:

```
using (Image img = Image.FromFile(@"c:\pic.bmp")) {
     img.Save(@"c:\pic.jpg" ,ImageFormat.Jpeg); 
}
```

Comment: I am not sure jet which format that will be, but lets say it will be format directly from memory card, I guess than it is bitmap. But I have to put water mark to image too.

Comment: For watermark, see eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224653/place-watermark-image-on-other-images-c-asp-net